# Can I include a blank in Case Like "X", "Y", "Z"?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a nested Case in my code. There are two variables to check, "src" and "dis"

The first case checks whether the src is within a list

```
src = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F").Value
dis = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
Select Case src

    'Attribution Model 1
    Case src Like "ARC", "BAC", "ICP", "IPRT", "JGRT", "KMG", "NAD", "NQS", "OMRT", "OSG*", "RCH", "ROPJG", "RTSUP", "SUP", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN", "WPR*"
        Select Case dis
            Case dis Like "", "ARC*", "BAC*", "ICP*", "IPRT*", "JGRT*", "KMG*", "NAD*", "NQS*", "OMRT*", "OSG*", "RCH*", "ROPJG*", "RTSUP*", "SUP*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN*", "WPR*"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
            Case Else
    'Attribution Model 2
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
            End Select

    'Attribution Model 3
    Case src Like "WEB*"
        If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AD").Value > 0 Then
        Select Case dis
            Case dis Like "", "ARC*", "BAC*", "ICP*", "IPRT*", "JGRT*", "KMG*", "NAD*", "NQS*", "OMRT*", "OSG*", "RCH*", "ROPJG*", "RTSUP*", "SUP*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN*", "WPR*"
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
            Case Else
    'Attribution Model 4
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
            End Select
        Else '<--- If URL = N
        Select Case dis
            Case dis Like "ARC*", "BAC*", "ICP*", "IPRT*", "JGRT*", "KMG*", "NAD*", "NQS*", "OMRT*", "OSG*", "RCH*", "ROPJG*", "RTSUP*", "SUP*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN*", "WPR*"
    'Attribution Model 6
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
            Case Else
    'Attribution Model 5
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
            End Select
        End If

    Case src Like "ARC", "BAC", "ICP", "IPRT", "JGRT", "KMG", "NAD", "NQS", "OMRT", "OSG*", "RCH", "ROPJG", "RTSUP", "SUP", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN", "WPR*"
                ' This is blank as ignored
            Case Else
        Select Case dis
            Case dis Like "ARC*", "BAC*", "ICP*", "IPRT*", "JGRT*", "KMG*", "NAD*", "NQS*", "OMRT*", "OSG*", "RCH*", "ROPJG*", "RTSUP*", "SUP*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN*", "WPR*"
    'Attribution Model 7
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
            Case Else
        End Select

End Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
```

I've tried changing all blank values where "dis" is checked to say something, like "DONK", then even when I have "Case dis like "DONK", "ARC" etc, it still skips over Result 1 and wants to write Result 2.

There always is something in src, so it should be "If src = List and if dis = List or blank, then result 1, otherwise result 2", however, it seems to disregard the result of the second Case and always gives me the "Case Else" result.

Comment: please show you exact code and some data sample: the one shown doesn't compile

Comment: Kindly provide a [repro].

Comment: @DisplayName - done mate, thanks.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me you could benefit from a helper function like this:

```
Function EqualsOrLikes(valToCheck As String, equals As Variant, likes As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim val As Variant

    Select Case True
        Case Not IsError(Application.Match(valToCheck, equals, 0))
            EqualsOrLikes = True
        Case Else
            For Each val In likes
                If valToCheck Like val Then
                    EqualsOrLikes = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
    End Select
End Function
```

to *feed* with:

- `src` or `dis` for `valToCheck`
- an array of full match values for `equals`
- an array of "like" match values for `likes`

for instance:

```
Sub x()
    Dim equals As Variant, likes As Variant
    equals = Array("ARC", "BAC", "ICP", "IPRT", "JGRT", "KMG", "NAD", "NQS", "OMRT", "RCH", "ROPJG", "RTSUP", "SUP", "TRN")
    likes = Array("OSG*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "WPR*")

    Dim src As String, dis As String
    src = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F").Value
    dis = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value

    Dim okDisEqualsOrLikes As Boolean
    okDisEqualsOrLikes = EqualsOrLikes(dis, equals, likes) ' this you can evaluate once for all subsequent checks

    Select Case True

        Case EqualsOrLikes(src, equals, likes)
            Select Case True
                Case dis = vbNullString Or okDisEqualsOrLikes
                    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
                Case Else
                    'Attribution Model 2
                    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
            End Select

        Case src Like "WEB*"
            If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AD").Value > 0 Then
                Select Case True
                    Case dis = vbNullString Or okDisEqualsOrLikes
                        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
                    Case Else
                        'Attribution Model 4
                        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
                End Select
            Else '<--- If URL = N
                Select Case True
                    Case okDisEqualsOrLikes
                        'Attribution Model 6
                        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
                    Case Else
                        'Attribution Model 5
                        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "N"
                End Select
            End If

        Case Else
            Select Case True
                Case okDisEqualsOrLikes
                    'Attribution Model 7
                    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AE").Value = "Y"
            End Select
        End Select

End Sub
```

a more coincise (although less elegant, at least to me) version of which is the following:

```
Sub x()
    Dim equals As Variant, likes As Variant
    equals = Array("ARC", "BAC", "ICP", "IPRT", "JGRT", "KMG", "NAD", "NQS", "OMRT", "RCH", "ROPJG", "RTSUP", "SUP", "TRN")
    likes = Array("OSG*", "TIN*", "TLA*", "WPR*")

    Dim src As String, dis As String
    src = Cells(ActiveCell.row, "F").value
    dis = Cells(ActiveCell.row, "G").value

    Dim okDisEqualsOrLikes As Boolean
    okDisEqualsOrLikes = EqualsOrLikes(dis, equals, likes) ' this you can evaluate once for all subsequent checks

    Select Case True

        Case EqualsOrLikes(src, equals, likes)
            Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "N"
            If dis = vbNullString Or okDisEqualsOrLikes Then Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "Y"

        Case src Like "WEB*"
            Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "N"
            If Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AD").value > 0 Then
                If dis = vbNullString Or okDisEqualsOrLikes Then Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "Y"
            Else '<--- If URL = N
                If okDisEqualsOrLikes Then Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "Y"
            End If

        Case Else
            If okDisEqualsOrLikes Then Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "Y"

    End Select    
End Sub
```

Comment: This plan seems so crazy it might just work! Thank you for this, I will try it first thing tomorrow when I'm back in work! I've gotten somewhere with SJR's code but it's now struggling in Attribution Model 6 where the dis is "" but it's still counting as a yes.

Comment: why/where would it seem crazy?

Comment: It was tongue in cheek, because it's a radical approach to my more mundane select case humdrum :)

Comment: I see. Well you may want to consider a less radical approach  in my edited answer last piece of code

Comment: Yep, that seems to work, the only problem is that it doesn't know what to do when it comes up against something that isn't in the src column. We get weird codes like "Recommend a Friend" and "Existing Customer" etc and these should be marked as a "N", but only if there isn't a match in the dis array. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Since my answer solved your _original_ question, you may then consider marking it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know why, when something isn't in the "src" array, it doesn't give a "N"?

Comment: Step through the code (place the cursor inside the code and press F8 to start it and stop at each subsequent statement to be executed) and see what is happening. And you'll see that if 1) `src` isn't in the `equals` nor `likes` array. 2)`src` isn't `Like "WEB*"` 3) `dis` isn't in the `equals` nor `likes` array, then nothing happens!. You may want to place `Cells(ActiveCell.row, "AE").value = "N"` right after last `Case Else` statement

Answer (score 2):

You have to reformulate your SELECT CASE. (The `src` bit doesn't need LIKE at all as you are checking exact values.)

```
Sub x()

Dim src, dis

src = "ARC"
dis = "ARCH"

Select Case src
    Case "ARC", "BAC", "TRN"
    Select Case True
        Case dis Like "DONK", dis Like "ARC*", dis Like "BAC*", dis Like "TRN*"
            MsgBox "Result 1"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Result 2"
    End Select
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott (assume it was you) - was just about to delete my answer...

Comment: Saw you there @ScottCraner .  Was going to ask on his answer \if `or` was preferable to just listing comma separated arguments in the Case.  It always seemed more appropriate to leave those to if statements which require those logic.

Comment: @Cyril - not sure, I think it's down to personal preference. Arguably clearer to state OR and not sure there is much argument for SC over IF other than it sometimes being clearer to read.

Comment: Hi SJR, I've got this "src = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F").Value
dis = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
Select Case src
    
    'Attribution Model 1
    Case src "ARC", "BAC", "ICP", "IPRT", "JGRT", "KMG", "NAD", "NQS", "OMRT", "OSG*", "RCH", "ROPJG", "RTSUP", "SUP", "TIN*", "TLA*", "TRN", "WPR*"
        Select Case True"     but it comes up with Syntax error...

Comment: I hear you about the readability.  I have not seen many people use `Case blah Or blih`, as opposed to `Case blah, blih` which is what was confusing me.

Comment: @RockandGrohl whoa... can you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58487850/edit) and add the updated code *as an edit* (not removing original scope and code) so that is more readable?  comment formatting doesn't really help in readability.  you can "@" tag ping back in the comments to reference your post.

Comment: @Cyril - see what you mean, me neither. However I suppose OR is immediately understandable whereas a comma is not unless you know SC syntax.

Comment: @SJR my original post has been updated with the full code. I think I do need "Like" on the original case as there can be weird src codes.

Comment: You're not using my code as far as I can see so not sure how I can help. Given the length of your full code do wonder if it can't be simplified though.

Comment: @SJR I did, but the problem is that sources which I define as "src" are user generated and someone can put in either "TIN" or "TIN - T Newspapers Ltd." etc. This means I have to use "Like" to allow the case to search with a wildcard included. Because of that, I then updated my post with the full code to allow people to contextually see what the problem is.  Haha, and here I was thinking the "Case Select" method would be easiest, would be very interested to know how to make it simpler, thanks for your time.

Comment: Well that's what my answer does - reformulate so it should work correctly. Have you tried it? There seems to be some repetition so that might be simplifiable.

Comment: @ SJR I did try it, and where I had "TIN - T Newspapers Ltd." it wasn't a match for Case TIN :(

Comment: There are two issues here. One, I reformulated the Select Case statements so have a look at that and try to work into your code. The second is the use of Like - by all means reinstate if you need it, it was just that your example didn't use wildcards.